# In python is there a way to know if an object "implements an interface" before I pass it to a function?

Tags: python, exception, object, introspection

I know this may sound like a stupid question, especially to someone who knows python's nature, but I was just wondering, **is there a way to know if an object "implements an interface" so as to say?**

To give an example of what I want to say:

let's say I have this function:

```
def get_counts(sequence):
     counts = {}
     for x in sequence:
         if x in counts:
             counts[x] += 1
         else:
             counts[x] = 1
     return counts
```

**My question is: Is there a way to make sure that the object passed to the function is `iterable`?** I know that in Java or C# I could do this by having the method accept any object that implements a specific interface, let's say (for example) `iIterable` like this: `void get_counts(iIterable sequence)`

**My guess is that in Python I would have to employ preemptive introspection checks** (in a `decorator`  perhaps?) and throw a custom `exception` if the object doesn't have an `__iter__` attribute). But is there a more ***pythonic*** way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Use polymorphism and duck-typing before `isinstance()` or interfaces

You generally define what you want to *do* with your objects, then either use polymorphism to adjust how each object responds to what you want to do, or you use duck typing; test if the object at hand can do the thing you want to do in the first place. This is the invocation versus introspection trade-off, conventional wisdom states that invocation is preferable over introspection, but in Python, duck-typing is preferred over `isinstance` testing.

So you need to work out *why* you need to filter on wether or not something is iterable in the first place; why do you need to know this? Just use a `try: iter(object)`, `except TypeError: # not iterable` to test.

Or perhaps you just need to throw an exception if whatever that was passed was not an iterable, as that would signal an error.

#### ABCs

With duck-typing, you may find that you have to test for multiple methods, and thus a `isinstance()` test may look a better option. In such cases, using a [Abstract Base Class (ABC)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) could also be an option; using an ABC let's you 'paint' several different classes as being the right type for a given operation, for example. Using a ABC let's you focus on the tasks that need to be performed rather than the specific implementations used; you can have a `Paintable` ABC, a `Printable` ABC, etc.

#### Zope interfaces and component architecture

If you find your application is using an *awful* lot of ABCs or you keep having to add polymorphic methods to your classes to deal with various different situations, the next step is to consider using a full-blown component architecture, such as the [Zope Component Architecture (ZCA)](http://www.muthukadan.net/docs/zca.html).

`zope.interface` interfaces are ABCs on steroids, especially when combined with the ZCA adapters. Interfaces document expected behaviour of a class:

```
if IFrobnarIterable.providedBy(yourobject):
    # it'll support iteration and yield Frobnars.
```

but it also let's you look up adapters; instead of putting all the behaviours for every use of shapes in your classes, you implement adapters to provide polymorphic behaviours for specific use-cases. You can adapt your objects to be printable, or iterable, or exportable to XML:

```
class FrobnarsXMLExport(object):
    adapts(IFrobnarIterable)
    provides(IXMLExport)

    def __init__(self, frobnariterator):
        self.frobnars = frobnariterator

    def export(self):
        entries = []
        for frobnar in self.frobnars:
            entries.append(
                u'<frobnar><width>{0}</width><height>{0}</height></frobnar>'.format(
                    frobnar.width, frobnar.height)
        return u''.join(entries)
```

and your code merely has to look up adapters for each shape:

```
for obj in setofobjects:
    self.result.append(IXMLExport(obj).export())
```

Comment: May I ask why is **invocation** prefered over **introspection**? Is it because introspection is costly?

Comment: @NlightNFotis: If you can just call the method, then you just saved yourself the test. Testing is an extra step, so if that can be avoided, just do so.

Comment: @NlightNFotis: but also see [Python Forgiveness vs. Permission and Duck Typing](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/175655/175663#175663) for performance tradeoffs between ducktyping and exception handling.

Comment: I was gonna ask this but a phone call halted me! You're in my mind bro! Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 11):

Python (since 2.6) has [abstract base classes](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-abstract-base-class) (aka virtual interfaces), which are [more flexible](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/#rationale) than Java or C# interfaces.  To check whether an object is iterable, use [`collections.Iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Iterable):

```
if isinstance(obj, collections.Iterable):
    ...
```

However, if your `else` block would just raise an exception, then the most Python answer is: *don't check*! It's up to your caller to pass in an appropriate type; you just need to document that you're expecting an iterable object.

Comment: Yeah but should I do this kind of introspection check inside the same method or inside another `decorator` method? I would say in a decorator method to make it way more readable, but that would bring performance issues if heavily used in the table. What would be more **pythonic**?

Comment: @NlightNFotis the most pythonic thing to do is to document what you expect and allow `TypeError` to be raised if the caller passes in an inappropriate type.

Answer (score 2):

The Pythonic way is to use duck typing and, "ask forgiveness, not permission".  This usually means performing an operation in a `try` block assuming it behaves the way you expect it to, then handling other cases in an `except` block.

Comment: This only makes sense if you already expect the instance to fit the interface and when you know that no side-effects will occur before you get an error.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the way that the community would recommend you do it:

```
import sys

def do_something(foo):
    try:
        for i in foo:
            process(i)
    except:
        t, ex, tb = sys.exc_info()
        if "is not iterable" in ex.message:
            print "Is not iterable"

do_something(True)
```

Or, you could use something like `zope.interface`.

Comment: I am quite sure, "the community" would not use an unspecified `except` statement, but would at least write `except TypeError:` to differentiate the error from other errors that might raise inside of `process()`