# What is the pythonic way to check the vaildity of constructor arguments?

Tags: python, types, error-handling, type-safety

For example take a simple class representing a person. The only class attribute is a string representing the persons name. I want to make sure that nobody tries to pass the constructor some other type of object like an int, or list...etc. This was my first attempt below I thought that this would return an obj of type None if the argument was not a str but it still seems to return a Person obj. I come from a "more" strongly typed language background and I am a little confused as how to handle my self in python. What does pythonic style say about this situation and type safety more generally? Should I raise an exception? Or find a way to return None? Or something else entirely.

```
class Person: 

    name = None

    def __init__(self, name):
        if not isinstance(name, str):
            return None
        self.name = name
```

Comment: I essentially made a similar question the other day, and you can find it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919772/in-python-is-there-a-way-to-know-if-an-object-implements-an-interface-before-i). **I urge you to read Martijn Pieter's answer** as it is very related to what you ask.

Comment: Why not use `self.name = str(name)`? That would accept everything that has a string representation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd want to raise an error within the `__init__` method:

```
if not isinstance(name,basestring):
    raise TypeError("I don't think that is a name ...")
```

*Note that `basestring` also includes `unicode` for python2.x, but isn't available in python3.x.

Careful though, there is nothing here to prevent a user from re-setting the person's name to a list after the `person` has been constructed.

```
jack = Person("Jack")
jack.name = ["cheese","steak"]  #???
```

If you want to have this safety built in, you'll need to start learning about [`property`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).

Comment: @JonClements -- Yeah, I suppose so.  Good call. :)

Comment: OMG - that's scary - we both just added that at the same time :) (the str/basestring thing that is) - Good point about properties though + 1:)

Comment: @JonClements -- We seem to have hive mind for this question.  We posted simultaneously as well...

Comment: @RocketDonkey -- I forgot to add the line : `isintance = isinstance` at the top ;-)

Comment: @mgilson Haha, should have figured :)

Comment: @mgilson -- +1 Thanks for the answers. I have seen duck-typing referenced in a couple of the links provided but I was not sure exactly what that means. Is that just a way of type checking where you use try: except: instead of isinstance()?

Comment: @vanattab -- Basically, yes.  The idea is that if the variable acts like a duck, and smells like a duck, and looks like a duck, then it must be a duck.

Answer (score 5):

That's about it - short of using some form of decorator, but generally, type checking isn't very Pythonic, although valid in some cases, your code should be:

```
def __init__(self, name):
    if not isinstance(name, basestring):
        raise TypeError('name must be str/unicode')
    # ...
```

Note that `basestring` is the parent of `str` and `unicode` in Python 2.x, so this would allow both - either use `str` (as you are now in 2.x) to not allow unicode (or vice versa - for any particular reason). In 3.x, `basestring` doesn't exist, you've just got `str`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that "type checking isn't [usually] very Pythonic"

Comment: @vanattab Further reading that might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950386/is-it-pythonic-to-check-function-argument-types

Answer (score 0):

I would not return `None` here but rather raise and exception to signify the incorrect object type.