# Python type hint for classes that support __getitem__

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I want to add type hints to a function that will accept any object with a `__getitem__` method. For instance, in

```
def my_function(hasitems, locator):
    hasitems[locator]
```

I don't want to restrict `hasitems` to be a specific type like `list` or `dict`. As long as it supports `__getitem__`, it's an appropriate argument to `my_function`. How can I annotate its type without being unnecessarily restrictive?

Edit: apparently PyCharm can deduce the appropriate hint in a number of common cases, but not in my actual use case. I can't post the code since it's for work, and I haven't been able to find a nonproprietary minimal example where PyCharm fails. In any case, the original question doesn't reference PyCharm and it is still a valid use case for type hints.

Comment: Make an `abc` with that single abstract method.

Comment: May I ask what is the use for such a hint? IDEs already deduct the hints automatically based on the usage. Are you using these hints for something else?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! In the example, PyCharm is indeed able to deduce the hint. For some reason, it can't in my actual use case.

Comment: Then upgrade. For me PyCharm yields for calling `my_function(5, 10)`:
> Type 'int' doesn't have expected attribute '__getitem__' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: This inspection detects type errors in function call expressions. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Types of function parameters can be specified in docstrings or in Python 3 function annotations.

Comment: I suggest you put your actual code in the question. This way we could be more helpful.

Comment: @LiranFunaro I quite agree. Since your comment I have been trying to find a minimal example where PyCharm fails to deduce the type hint, but this is actually difficult. I believe the original question is still valid even if it may not apply to my use case :)

Comment: What Python version are you using?  3.7 introduced Protocols, which are supposed to address this problem: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/

Comment: Python 3.6.6. That's the company standard, at least for now, so I can't switch. Thanks for the pointer though!

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Protocols seems great addition and may actually solve a question I asked a long time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830996/a-way-to-verify-that-an-unknown-module-is-obliged-to-a-specific-interface-pytho
However it doesn't seem to work even in the latest version of python.

Comment: @LiranFunaro Hmm, it looks like you're right.  Now that I check again, it looks like that PEP is still a draft.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Weirdly enough, PyCharm does recognize `Protocol` and `runtime` and the hinting works correctly inside of PyCharm. But the code does not run.

Comment: @LiranFunaro It looks like they're in [typing-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) for the moment, but mypy already knows about how to use them for structural subtyping.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Correct! This works. I guess this is the answer OP is looking for.
This now works: `from typing_extensions import Protocol` from Python 3.6

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're willing to install a not-quite-offical extension to `typing`, [typing-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/), you can use a `Protocol`, which should be an implementation of [PEP-0544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/):

```
from typing_extensions import Protocol
from typing import Any

class GetItem(Protocol):
    def __getitem__(self: 'Getitem', key: Any) -> Any: pass

class BadGetItem:
    def __getitem__(self, a: int, b: int) -> Any: pass

def do_thing(arg: GetItem):
    pass

do_thing(dict())  # OK
do_thing(BadGetItem())  # Fails with explanation of correct signature
do_thing(1)  # Fails
```

Comment: This is the best solution so far, but it ignores the function's arguments.
It does not verify the function's number of arguments and the argument's types.

Comment: @LiranFunaro What makes you say that?  When I run mypy on the above example (which I just added a test case to), it fails `BadGetItem` objects because of incompatible signatures.

Comment: I'm basing my response on the fact that PyCharm does not issue a warning when the parameters are incompatible. Also, `isinstance()` returns `True` for the same case.

Comment: @LiranFunaro I'm using command line mypy 0.670.  When I try to use a `Protocol` in an `isinstance` check, I get an error `TypeError: Instance and class checks can only be used with @runtime protocols`

Comment: You should add `@runtime` decrator to the Protocol.

Comment: You should probably replace `Any` with two separate `TypeVar` instances. I'm thinking `K = TypeVar('K')` and `V = TypeVar('V')`, and then in `class GetItem(Protocol)` the signature would be: `__getitem__(self, key: K) -> V`. And of course implement `__class_getitem__` to support `GetItem[SomeKeyType, SomeValueType]` in type hints.

Comment: Of course instead of implementing `__class_getitem__` manually, inheriting from `Generic[K, V]` seems like the more proper way. I haven't tested if it actually passes various type linters out there, but I would try something like `class GetItem(Protocol, Generic[K, V])`.

Comment: this only works if the argument to `__getitem__` is called `key` :(

Comment: here is a way that actually works:
```python
class HasGetItem(Protocol):
    def __getitem__(self, __key:Any) -> Any:
        ...
```
you have to add __ before the argument name and it won't be angry at parameter name mismatch

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you essentially want to define your own [abstract base class (abc)](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-abstract-base-class).

Following the documentation above, you can define a custom abc that only dictates the presence of `__getitem__`, but let's use a predefined one for an example. 
The [`Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping) abc consists of `__getitem__` and a few other magic methods. You can use abcs in `isinstance`, but you can also directly use them as a type annotations:

```
def foo(bar: Mapping):
    pass
```

Or, using the [extended type hinting support of ABCs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics) do even fancies things, which you already saw in other answers:

```
def foo(bar: Mapping[Any, Any]):
    pass
```

Comment: `Mapping` is not appropriate here, it will be overly restrictive.

Comment: That's why I said I only use it as an example and OP can define their own ABC that only consists of `__getitem__`

Comment: If this is truly the best way, I'm disappointed in the `typing` module. My use case must be quite common.

Comment: You can always just doo `hasattr(x, '__getitem__')` or wrap a lookup in try-except. python's type hinting looks and works clunky indeed imo

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not interested in guarding the input type. I just want a type hint that works with PyCharm.

Comment: I don't see how abc will help here. Creating a new ABC will not make `list` and `dict` inherit from this ABC.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for dict and list, but not for any generic type:

```
from typing import Any, Mapping, Sequence, Union

def my_function(hasitems: Union[Mapping, Sequence], locator: Any) -> Any:
    return hasitems[locator]
```

Comment: Mmmm not quite. A `Mapping` is much more than merely `__getitem__`. Note also, `list` objects support `__getitem__`, but they are not a `Mapping`

Comment: `typing.Sequence` is another ABC that "defines" `__getitem__`, though even that may be more specific than the OP wants. (As it also mandates `__len__`, `__iter__`, etc.)

Comment: @LiranFunaro Thanks, but I specifically asked for a solution that is not restricted to `dict` and `list`.

Comment: @chepner Correct, mandating `__len__` and `__iter__` is not ok.

Comment: I think what you are asking for, then, is almost *too* broad. Sure, classes that support `__getitem__` but nothing else *can* exist, but is there any reason to *support* them? Unless  you have a specific class in mind that *isn't* covered by `Union[Mapping,Sequence]`, I would use that until it actually presents a problem.