# Subscriptable Type in Python typing

Tags: python, typing

I would like to typecheck that the parameter of a function is subscriptable. How do I do this with Python's `typing` module?

I have searched the documetation but didn't find anything. But maybe it is possible to create a custom `Type`. How would I do that?

Comment: I know nothing about Python or MyPy, but maybe a duck type including `__getitem__` would work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python type hint for classes that support \_\_getitem\_\_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127855/python-type-hint-for-classes-that-support-getitem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To hint the standard `__getitem__` behaviour, use the generic versions of `collections.abc`, such as [`typing.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Sequence), [`typing.MutableSequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.MutableSequence), [`typing.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Mapping), or [`typing.MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.MutableMapping).

```
from typing import Mapping

def get(container: Mapping, key):
    return container[key]

get({1: 'one', 2: 'two'}, 2)
```

To type hint *any* type that supports `__getitem__`, define a custom `typing.Protocol` with the desired behaviour.

```
from typing import Protocol, Any

class Lookup(Protocol):
      def __getitem__(self, key) -> Any: ...

def get(container: Lookup, key):
    return container[key]

get(['zero', 'one', 'two'], 2)
```

---

Note that the sequence and mapping types are generic, and a protocol can be define as generic as well.

```
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar

K = TypeVar('K', contravariant=True)
V = TypeVar('V', covariant=True)


class Lookup(Protocol[K, V]):
    def __getitem__(self, key: K) -> V: ...


def get(container: Lookup[K, V], key: K) -> V:
    return container[key]


get({1: 'one', 2: 'two'}, 2)    # succeeds type checking
get({1: 'one', 2: 'two'}, '2')  # fails type checking
```

Comment: This is better than the solution provided at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127855/python-type-hint-for-classes-that-support-getitem because it shows how to access the types of the key and value as well

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines (completely untested, though) should do it:

```py
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar

K = TypeVar("K")
V = TypeVar("V")

class Subscriptable(Protocol[K, V]):
    def __getitem__(self, k: K) -> V:
        ...
```