# Set Python type hint for a object having specific methods

Tags: python

My goal is to specify **type hint** to be of an **object of a class** that has two methods  `fit` and `transform`

I'm not sure how to achieve that

```py
def apply(obj : callable) -> None :

 pass
```

This would specify that `obj`  should be callable but that's not what I want. I want to specify that obj should have a `obj.fit()` and `obj.transform()`

Comment: You can use a [`typing.Protocol`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/) which lets you use structural typing

Comment: What you want to do is typehinting your `obj` to be of abstract class XYZ which forces all descendents to implement the abstract methods. Or typehinting that `obj` "implements" the interface XYZ with those 2 methods.

Comment: @PatrickArtner actually, python type-hints support structural typing using `typing.Protocol`, in addition to the normal nominal typing. You are right, though, the alternative is to define some class and have all those objects inherit from that class, but that's gross, structural typing is much nicer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python type hint for classes that support \_\_getitem\_\_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127855/python-type-hint-for-classes-that-support-getitem)

Answer (score 0):

Let's look to the example below, I hope it'll help you

```
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar, Generic


class HasRunEngineMethod(Protocol):
    def run_engine(self) -> None:
        ...


T = TypeVar('T', bound='HasRunEngineMethod')


class GearBase(Generic[T]):
    """Represents the gear base."""

    def run_engine(self) -> None: ...


class Airplane(GearBase):

    def run_engine(self): print("Airplane engine is running")

    def __str__(self): return "Airplane"


class Car(GearBase):

    def run_engine(self): print("Car engine is running")

    def __str__(self): return "Car"


gears = [Airplane(), Car()]


def send_gears_to_factory(gear_obj: HasRunEngineMethod) -> None:
    gear_obj.run_engine()
    print(f"Sending {gear_obj} to the factory")


for gear in gears:
    send_gears_to_factory(gear)
```

Comment: btw, Mypy said that this code without issues