# Is the __eq__ method defined as part of a Protocol?

Tags: python, protocols

Consider the following ADT:

```
T = TypeVar("T")

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Branch(Generic[T]):
    value: T
    left: Tree[T]
    right: Tree[T]


Tree = Branch[T] | None
```

Note the requirement for `from __future__ import annotations` since `Tree` is used before it is defined.

Suppose we want to implement a function to check whether a tree contains a given element. A possible implementation is the following:

```
def contains(t: Tree[T], x: T) -> bool:
    match t:
        case None:
            return False
        case Branch(value, left, right):
            return x == value or contains(left, x) or contains(right, x)
```

This all type checks nicely, except for the fact that it's wrong. We have no guarantee that type `T` supports equality checking.

I'm new to Python but I understand that `Protocol`s are the way of defining shared functionality. Is `__eq__` part of a `Protocol` that would allow us to put a bound on `T` in this case, something equivalent to Haskell's `Eq` type class?

If not then are there any other potential ways to get better type safety here?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55127855/4996248) seems similar. That question is from 2019 and Python type hints are rapidly evolving, so there might be additional solutions since then.

Comment: `__eq__` is a magic method, if overwrite it python will use it when comparing your object

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've come up with so far is:

```
def contains(t: Tree[T], x: T) -> bool:
    match t:
        case None:
            return False
        case Branch(value, left, right):
            try:
                return x == value or contains(left, x) or contains(right, x)
            except NotImplementedError:
                return False
```

I don't particularly like this but at least it's safe (I think).